# Custom title bar vs. layout with header

Tags: android

I recently thought of adding a custom title bar to my app (with "find me" and home button and such) and then I thought what is the reason of using a custom title bar at top instead of just a normal layout and using it as an include tag at the top of my XML's

What are the pros and cons of each? Is there realy a difference?

EDIT: one difference ive found so far is that the custom title bar has a shadows automaticly

Comment: users typically use the back button to go back! why take up extra space for something already on the device!?

Comment: Well not realy for back button for home button and locate me button (on map) and a few other things

Comment: binnyb is right about back key if it is already there in device.

Comment: Consider using floating buttons on the bottom right of the screen while the main window scrolls.

Comment: thanks ask for the alternatives but that is not my question I am aware of other options I just want to know the differences between the two I listed thanks

Answer (score 0):

For having back and home button titlebar, you should define normal layout for the same. Because it is easy to implement as compared to customized the native title bar. And we can create normal layout as we wants with any color/height/width/image backround/etc.

I suggest you to go with defining normal layout for the title bar instead of customizing the native title bar.

Comment: also the custom bar is easy to implement. Is it restricted to the default title bar size and theme? I think it is not

Answer (score 0):

You can extend LinearLayout to create a new layout with your title bar. The advantage is you can then customise the title bar for different activities that use it. Some may not want to display the find button for instance.

If you use include in XML you don't have the same flexibility.
I would create a custom layout with the title bar.

Comment: I do not understand you. The suggestion you made is less flexible and does not answer my question :)

Comment: Your question was 'Custom title bar vs. layout with header' which is fairly vague. I had to guess from that that you wanted to compare a custom title bar implemented using a layout with a layout XML file using include to include a header layout. You need to be more specific about the entities you are trying to compare. What, for example, is a 'custom title bar'?

Comment: Custom title bar is a feature which allows you to use your own view instead of the default title bar. My title was edited by someone - and you understood correctly however extending linear layout does in now way help me make this more flexible